# Removing a character from a column of symbols

Tags: kdb

I have a table with columns containing numbers, one column contains two letters before each number in the column.

How can I remove these two letters in this column.

Comment: Welcome, to improve your experience on Stack Overflow please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) an [On Topic question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and the [Question Check list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) and [the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and if not already done, [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Answer (score 3):

As a symbol is only a reference to a string, you will need to evaluate it first before operating on the underlying string.

Using drop with the each right operator will remove the first 2 elements from the list and then you can cast it back to a symbol format.

With a list

```
q)l:`aa1`bb2
q)string l
"aa1"
"bb2"
q)2_/:string l
,"1"
,"2"
q)`$2_/:string l
`1`2
```

You can embed this in an update statement, replacing l with your column name.

If the number of distinct symbols is low you can use `.Q.fu`. This takes a function, applys it on each of the distinct symbols once and copies the result over to the rest of the list which will be faster when the operation is expensive, which string operations often are

```
q)\t .Q.fu[{`$2_/:string x};l]
19
q)\t `$2_/:string l
625
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your table looks something like this:

```
q)t:([]a:1 2 3; b:`aa1`aa2`aa3; c:1 2 3)
q)t
a b c
-------
1 aa1 1
2 aa2 2
3 aa3 3
```

You can use

```
q)@[t;`b;"F"$2_'string@]
a b c
-----
1 1 1
2 2 2
3 3 3
```

This will cast the original symbols to a string, drop the first 2 chars in column b then cast to a Float.
You may wish to cast them to an integer, in order to do so you can do something like this:

```
q)@[t;`b;"I"$2_'string@]
a b c
-----
1 1 1
2 2 2
3 3 3
```

Kind regards,
Shari

Answer (score 1):

Or in qsql:

```
q)t:([]a:1 2 3; b:`aa1`aa2`aa3; c:1 2 3)
q)update b:"J"$2_'string b from t
```

If b is not a symbol, but a char list, you can remove the call to